# Not refreshing screen in programmatically filled TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tableview

When I scroll down and up again my text in tableView will disappear.

[image] [image]

And my code is:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [screenDefBuild.elementsToTableView count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    ScreenListElements *currentScreenElement = [screenDefBuild.elementsToTableView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = currentScreenElement.objectName;

    currentRow++;    
    return cell;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [tableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}
```

I also want to fill my table view to entire screen. (grey strap on the top).

Comment: try this hide this code //if(cel==nil).... then scroll now

Comment: Both of those comments are exceptionally bad ideas and break several system optimisations for table views.

Comment: To solve the grey strap problem, give your tableview background color as white

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you're doing with this variable

```
currentRow++;
```

But whatever you use that for, i'd wager its breaking your code.

the `UITableView` will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` every time a cell is about to appear on screen regardless of whether it has been on screen before or not. When you scroll down and then scroll back up this variable will have increased beyond the bounds of your data, hence you get empty cells.

You need to design this method in such a way that it can create any cell in the table view at any time. You can't rely on the order that the cells will be made and with scrolling you will have to make the same cell over and over again. Only use `indexPath` to figure out which cell you are currently supposed to be making.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I'm not using it anymore. This is not there anymore, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Then you gotta look at `[screenDefBuild.elementsToTableView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` or  `currentScreenElement.objectName` because they're returning nil the second time they're called for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, ok, i'm on it. I will post back if i figure it out.

Comment: @SimpleMan jackslash is right, you dont need to increment anything or use for loop inside cellForRowAtIndexPath  method

Comment: SimpleMan to easily test what jackslash said you can try  `cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"test: %@",currentScreenElement.objectName];` then you'll see if null values are the case

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279585/loosing-data-in-nsobject-class <- i'm put more detail there. After yours advice this question doesn't cover my problem.

Comment: Oh, i have a weak property deep inside my object. What's a silly mistake. Sorry. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the second part of the question- grey strap. You are adding the table view to current view, so you should use the size property of `self.view.frame` but not the origin. You want this to be set to 0,0.

Change

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

to

```
CGRect viewFrame=self.view.frame;
viewFrame.origin=CGPointZero;
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
```

As for the first part of your question- it's strange, as you seem to do everything properly. One thing i may suggest is to add `[tableView reloadData];` in the end of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: This isn't the case. a view's bounds has the origin `CGPointZero` by definition (unless you change it). The bounds is the view's internal space in its own co-ordinates. Also adding `reloadData` at the end of `viewDidLoad` is not going to help as the `tableView` is populated Initially but fails after scrolling. `viewDidLoad` isn't called again here.

Comment: you are right, i got it confused with view.frame. As for the `viewDidLoad`- i know it's not called there, that was like a blind shot